# MySQL: How do I use COUNT while performing a 3 way left join?

Tags: mysql

I am performing a 3 way left join to retrieve message information. Along with the messages, I also want the number of votes each message has. Every vote a message has is represented by an entry in the votes table. I want to return all message and mark information along with the number of entries a given message has in the votes table.

**query**

```
 var query = ([
        'SELECT * FROM marks',
        'LEFT JOIN messages',
          'ON marks.messageId = messages.id',
        'LEFT JOIN votes',
          'ON votes.messageId = messages.id',
        'WHERE marks.x between ? AND ?',
          'AND marks.y between ? AND ?',
        'ORDER BY timestamp DESC'
    ]).join(' ');
```

**schema**

```
CREATE TABLE marks (
  id int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  x float(10, 6),
  y float(10, 6),
  z float(10, 6),
  timestamp timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  messageId int(5),
  FOREIGN KEY (messageId) REFERENCES messages(id),
  userToken VARCHAR(255),
  FOREIGN KEY (userToken) REFERENCES users(token)
);

CREATE TABLE messages (
  id int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  messageString text,
  score int(5) DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE votes (
  id int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  userToken VARCHAR(255),
  FOREIGN KEY (userToken) REFERENCES users(token),
  messageId int(5),
  FOREIGN KEY (messageId) REFERENCES messages(id)
);
```

**Sample Data:**

```
mysql> select * from marks;
+----+------------+-------------+------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
| id | x          | y           | z          | timestamp           | messageId | userToken |
+----+------------+-------------+------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
|  3 |  37.783600 | -122.408974 |  69.000000 | 2015-04-08 16:15:27 |         3 | NULL      |
|  6 | 535.000000 |  325.000000 | 325.000000 | 2015-04-09 14:36:39 |         6 | live      |
|  7 | 535.000000 |  325.000000 | 325.000000 | 2015-04-09 14:40:10 |         7 | live      |
|  8 | 535.000000 |  325.000000 | 325.000000 | 2015-04-09 14:41:00 |         8 | live      |
|  9 | 535.000000 |  325.000000 | 325.000000 | 2015-04-09 14:41:42 |         9 | live      |
| 10 | 535.000000 |  325.000000 | 325.000000 | 2015-04-09 14:43:44 |        10 | live      |
+----+------------+-------------+------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from messages;
+----+--------------------+-------+
| id | messageString      | score |
+----+--------------------+-------+
|  3 | Brooks was here    |  9001 |
|  4 | NULL               |     0 |
|  5 | NULL               |     0 |
|  6 | NULL               |     0 |
|  7 | NULL               |     0 |
|  8 | OMG I LOVE JALEPNO |     0 |
|  9 | OMG I LOVE JALEPNO |     0 |
| 10 | OMGEE BEEBEEQUE    |   100 |
+----+--------------------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from votes;
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | userToken | messageId |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  2 | grgrdg    |         3 |
|  3 | live      |         3 |
|  5 | live      |        10 |
|  6 | live      |        10 |
|  7 | live      |        10 |
|  8 | live      |        10 |
|  9 | live      |        10 |
| 10 | live      |         9 |
| 11 | live      |         9 |
| 12 | live      |         9 |
+----+-----------+-----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Could you please post some sample data and the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT(votes.id)` and `GROUP BY marks.id, messages.id`

By counting votes.id, you will get 0 votes when that message has no votes

```
SELECT  marks.id
,       marks.x
,       marks.y
,       marks.z
,       marks.timestamp
,       marks.messageId
,       marks.userToken
,       messages.messageString
,       messages.score
,       COUNT(votes.id)
FROM    marks
LEFT JOIN messages ON messages.id = marks.messageId
LEFT JOIN votes ON votes.messageId = messages.id
GROUP BY marks.id, messages.id
```

Answer (score 1):

If your current query works fine for you. 
I can't recognize language you use.

But in regular mysql you can do something like:

```
SELECT marks.*, messages.messageString , votes.votes_counter 
FROM marks
LEFT JOIN messages
 ON marks.messageId = messages.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT messageId, COUNT(*) as votes_counter 
  FROM votes
  GROUP BY messageId
  ) as votes
 ON votes.messageId = messages.id
WHERE marks.x between ? AND ?
 AND marks.y between ? AND ?
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by writing a subquery for the number of votes per message. For that, you only need the votes table:

```
SELECT messageId, COUNT(*) AS numVotes
FROM votes
GROUP BY messageId;
```

Once you have that, outer join it to the other tables, and use COALESCE() to replace empty vote count messages with 0:

```
SELECT m.*, ms.*, COALESCE(t.numVotes, 0)
FROM marks m
LEFT JOIN messages ms ON ms.messageId = m.messageId
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT messageId, COUNT(*) AS numVotes
   FROM votes
   GROUP BY messageId) t ON t.messageId = ms.messageId;
```